# How to replace a line in sed with unknown amount of whitespace?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to replace a line in a config file with sed. But the line I am trying to replace contains an unknown amount of whitespace:

```
conf  is    foo
conf   is    bar
config    is      foobar
```

I've tried to match the whitespace characters with `\s+` without luck:

`$ sed -r 's|conf\s+is\s+foo|conf  is  boo|g' file.txt`

I would like to replace `conf  is    foo` with `conf  is  boo`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` doesn't support `\s`, you have to use `[[:blank:]]` instead:

```sh
sed -r 's|conf[[:blank:]]+is[[:blank:]]+foo|conf  is  boo|g' file.txt
```